# appengine / unable to deploy / iam troubleshooting

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-build, google-iam

The given service account is `{project_id}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

It has the following iam roles :

- `Editor`
- `Cloud Build Editor` (manually added, to verify if it was the reason behind this issue)

I have :

- downloaded the corresponding service account key on my laptop to `{local_path}/.gcloud.json`
- activated this service account via `gcloud auth
  activate-service-account {project_id}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
  --key-file={local_path}/.gcloud.json`
- set the `$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var to be
  `{local_path}/.gcloud.json`

Deploying with the following :

```
gcloud app deploy --project {project_id} \
  --quiet \
  --verbosity=debug \
  --account {project_id}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
  ./dispatch.yaml \
  ./app/app.yaml
```

I keep hitting the following error :

```
"Permission to create cloud build is denied. 'Cloud Build Editor' role is required for the deployment: ht..."
```

Checking Google cloud build on the gcloud ui, the build is created, but fails everytime (so it matches the given error returned from the command line)

I just have no clue why it happens; any help would be highly appreciated

Regards

Comment: Did you enabled cloud builder api?

Comment: @marian.vladoi as mentioned above : `Checking Google cloud build on the gcloud ui, the build is created, but fails everytime` so yeah, it is enabled, builds are created for each `gcloud app deploy` commands, every builds are crashing immediately with the provided above error

Comment: Are you using the right account - gcloud auth list?

Comment: yep it has been checked too, running this command do show that the account is the default (there an * on the left side of the service account name)

Comment: to be honest it really feels like there is an opaque bug, I've created another project to verify the very same setup; it works perfectly. it really feels like am looking for a needle in a haystack. the thing is, I worry now that such issue could happen again, so i'd be better off to find out what happened here

Comment: do you have this service agent account on your project: service-[PROJECT-ID]@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202462/discussion-between-ben-and-marian-vladoi).

Comment: Try to deactivate and reactivate the AppEngine API? Sometime, when major update happen and if your service has been activate long time ago, or in an alpha or beta version, there are things not provisioned automatically. To reset the API activation can solve issues.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the project is quite recent (a week ago); I've disabled the appengine project, disabled the appengine admin api (there was also the appengine flexible; haven't tried). re-enabling it all; the expected cloudbuild service account do not get recreated unfortunately /:

Comment: I could just switch project; eventhough it feels buggy; now i am doubting about my ability to avoid another occurence of such issue on any given project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When enabling the Cloud Run Api, 3 services acounts are created:

1. compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com,Default compute service account, Role: Editor
2. service-@containerregistry.iam.gserviceaccount.com, Google Container Registry Service Agent, Role: Editor
3. service-@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com, Google Cloud Run Service Agent, Role: Cloud Run Service Agent

The last two services account are Google-managed service account used to access the APIs of Google Cloud Platform services [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts?_ga=2.168174629.-566201694.1566725932&_gac=1.217018852.1573873591.Cj0KCQiAtrnuBRDXARIsABiN-7AXNm74nfcR6JLA6t3viJz4TH4bWHQW2JRmw2fqieLv5WGRFgBDntcaAsXfEALw_wcB#google-managed_service_accounts)

> By default, Cloud Run revisions are using the Compute Engine default
>   service account
>   (PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com), which has the
>   Project > Editor IAM role. This means that by default, your Cloud Run
>   revisions have read and write access to all resources in your GCP
>   project.

When enabling Google App Engine Flexible Environment API, 2 services accounts related to Cloud Run are created:

1. @cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com, Role: Cloud Build Service Account
2. service-@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com, Cloud Build Service Account, Role: Cloud Build Service Agent

When enabling App Engine Admin API, no extra services accounts are being created.

The command : `gcloud beta app repair`

> This command will restore the App Engine staging
>   bucket if it has been deleted. It will no longer restore the service
>   account, instead, the IAM service account undelete API must be used
>   for the purpose.

After deploying a google app engine, at least 4 buckets are created in the google cloud storage:

a. [project-id].appspot.com

b. staging.[project-id].appspot.com

c. artifacts.[project-id].appspot.com

d. vm-containers.[project-id].appspot.com

So I think you deleted the staging bucket or a service account by accident.

Answer (score 0):

as opaque as efficient : `gcloud beta app repair`, which restores required App Engine features to the current application